# How add columns to a row in Grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, grid

I have a MainGrid in Wpf (not a DataGrid) it has 3 rows(0.1 and 2) i have made rows using xaml at design time now at run time behind a menu button i want  to add 2 column to row 1 of the main grid.

The hard part is that only break the row 1 into 2 columnn and not the whole Grid.

i know that to add new rows and columns one can use rowdefination and columndefination but

couldnt find anything here:

```
 MainGrid.RowDefinitions.ElementAt(1).SetValue...;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you add a `Grid` with 1 row and 2 columns to that row instead. And put your contents in that `Grid`. That will be easier.

Comment: yeah tried it, GridView newGrid = new GridView (); Grid.SetRow(newGrid, 1);

Comment: but its giving argument cannot convert errot

Comment: yeah got it working thanks.                                           Grid newGrid = new Grid ();
             Grid.SetRow(newGrid, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(newGrid, 1);

            MainGrid.Children.Add(newGrid);

Answer (score 1):

make the column span = 2 for all the controls that you add in row 2 and 3...